# Using TagHelpers vs ViewComponents in ASP.NET MVC6

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to understand the use case differences between TagHelpers and ViewComponents in asp.net 5 because the end result functionality seems very similar. We have TagHelpers that can create new HTML tags that get parsed by the Razor engine and then ViewComponents that get explicitly invoked. Both return some HTML content, both are backed by their respective base classes, both have async versions of methods they can implement to get their work done.

So when would one be used over another? Or am I missing some information?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's definitely some conceptual overlap between TagHelpers and ViewComponents. TagHelpers are your utility to work with HTML where ViewComponents are your way to stick to C#, do isolated work and then spit out HTML. I'll go into each in detail:

**ViewComponents**
Your conceptually equivalent mini-controller; you will see that many of the methods/properties that ViewComponents expose are very familiar to those that exist on a Controller. Now as for invoking ViewComponents, that's more equivalent to utilizing HTML helpers (one thing TagHelpers make better). To sum up ViewComponents: Their primary purpose is to feel like a controller, stay in C# land (there may be no need to add utility to HTML), do smaller/isolated work and then spit out stringified HTML.

**TagHelpers**
A utility that enables you to work along side existing HTML or create new HTML elements that modify what happens on a page. Unlike ViewComponents TagHelpers can target any existing HTML and modify its behavior; example: you could add a *conditional* attribute to all HTML elements that would conditionally render the element server side. TagHelpers also allow you to intermingle common HTML terms, ex:

`<myTagHelper class="btn">Some Content</myTagHElper>`

As you can see we're adding a class attribute to our TagHelper just as if it were HTML. To do this in ViewComponents, you'd need to pass in a dictionary of attributes or something equivalent (unnatural). Lastly multiple TagHelpers can run over a single HTML element; each having their own stage at modifying output (allows entry for modular TagHelper toolkits). To sum TagHelpers up: They can do anything that ViewComponents can do and more BUT do not feel familiar to things like Controllers that ASP.NET developers are used to; also some projects may not want to intermingle server side HTML.

**Extra:**
I recently did a video showcasing the benefits of TagHelpers. Basically a walk through of what they're good at and how to use them. You can watch it [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Web+Camps+TV/Create-your-own-Domain-Specific-Language-in-ASPNET-with-TagHelpers).

Answer (score 3):

When deciding which one to use I always consider how complex the HTML of the component will be.

If it's something simple like a tree view or a pager

```
<ul class="jstree">
    <li>Node 1</li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

That is candidate for **tag helper**, because it's simple. Large HTML in a C# code would be hard to maintain.

---

On the other hand if it's complex HTML with many divs, images and configuration like a full blown menu where it can be vertical or horizontal that's your **view component**. Benefit of view component is that you can use multiple views so for menu so you can separate **horizontal.cshtml** & **vertical.cshtml** while reusing same backend code.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that in .Net Core 1.1, you can call a ViewComponent using the tagHelper syntax.

Regarding Taylor's comment "Their primary purpose is to feel like a controller", it is true, but since you cannot directly call this "micro-controller" directly, the "controller-like" behavior is limited in that you can only create a part of a page, you cannot call it again (say via an ajax call, an Edit Action, etc).

Answer (score 2):

One primary difference between TagHelpers and ViewComponents relates to how much work needs to be done by the object.  TagHelpers are fairly basic, requiring only a single class that overrides the `Process` method to produce the output of the TagHelper.  The downside is that if you do any complex work to create inner HTML in the TagHelper, it has to all be done in code.  In a ViewComponent, you have a mini-controller capable of doing a lot more work, plus it returns a view, where you have actual Razor syntax code that can be mapped to a model.

Another post mentioned that ViewComponents are more "HTML Helper"-y in how you call them.  ASP.NET 1.1 addressed that issue, so that you can call it with

```
<vc:view-component-name param1="value1" param2="value2></vc:view-component-name>
```

For most purposes, a TagHelper has a definite advantage, because it's easier.  But if you need a more robust solution, ViewComponent is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

And yet something that kind of defeats the purpose of View Components (IMHO) is that from the View Component class there seems to be no way to access the Inner Html of the VC if you use the tag helper syntax:

```
 <vc:MyComponent id="1" att="something">
     Some HTML markup you would not want to put in an attribute
 </vc:MyComponent>
```

There are however good applications of a VC such as the **Bootstrap Navigation Bar View Component** I saw in a *TechieJourney* blog post.

Comment: You can wrap your ViewComponent in a custom TagHelper as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44913297/is-it-possible-to-call-viewcomponent-from-custom-taghelper-in-asp-net-mvc-6). This way you will be able to access HTML markup inside TagHelper and pass it into the ViewComponent when needed.