# Is it possible to call ViewComponent from custom TagHelper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I'm writing a custom TagHelper and want to render a ViewComponent inside it. 
Something similar to what vc:xyz tag helper does, but in a more controlled way, so that I can determine at runtime which ViewComponent to render.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 11):

In order to do that, you need to inject IViewComponentHelper into your TagHelper, contextualize it and then use it to render any ViewComponent depending on your application logic. Here is a quick illustration:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("widget", Attributes = WidgetNameAttributeName)]
public class WidgetTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private const string WidgetNameAttributeName = "name";
    private readonly IViewComponentHelper _viewComponentHelper;

    public WidgetTagHelper(IViewComponentHelper viewComponentHelper)
    {
        _viewComponentHelper = viewComponentHelper;
    }

    [HtmlAttributeNotBound]
    [ViewContext]
    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

    [HtmlAttributeName(WidgetNameAttributeName)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        ((IViewContextAware)_viewComponentHelper).Contextualize(ViewContext);

        var content = await _viewComponentHelper.InvokeAsync(typeof(WidgetViewComponent), new { name = Name });
        output.Content.SetHtmlContent(content);
    }
}
```

Also, keep in mind that self-closing tags will NOT work:

```
<widget name="abc" />
```

Use this form instead:

```
<widget name="abc"></widget>
```

Comment: Thank you for this helpful answer. I just tried it and self-closing tag worked for me.  But what does Contextualize() actually do?

Comment: @Ray cool, they probably fixed that in later versions of a framework. Contextualize does something to make it work, haha. It was a long time ago and I guess I've tried different random things I saw people doing around the internets and that particular thing work. You can always look into framework's source code if you are thaaaat curious! ;)

Answer (score 4):

A follow up on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44913298/5050045).

There is no need to write end tag when calling the tag helper. Just set the [TagMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.taghelpers.taghelperoutput.tagmode) in ProcessAsync:

```
output.TagMode = TagMode.StartTagAndEndTag;
output.Content.SetHtmlContent(content);
```

Then `<widget name="abc" />` works perfectly fine.

Alternatively, you can render the content of the view component in place of the `widget` tag without rendering the tag itself:

```
output.SuppressOutput();
output.PostElement.SetHtmlContent(content);
```

I also noticed that adding self-closing tags in the view component's [view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.1#view-search-path) makes them appear wrong in the final result, but that may be a different topic.